# resnet50 implementation for semantic segmentation

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am new to resnet models.

I want to implement a resnet50 model for semantic segmentation
I am following the code from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkNIBBBvcPs&t=224s) video, but my numclasses is 21. I have a few questions:

1. If i pass in any rgb jpeg image into the model, I get an output of size (1, 21). What does this output represent?
2. Since I am doing semantic segmentation, my images dont have any rgb channels, so what should I put for image_channels in self.conv1?
3. I pass in an image for training, attached below (this image has a label ranging from 0 - 20 for the object class). After the image passes through the resnet mode, and I get an output of something in the shape of (1, 21). What does this output represent?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output from the ResNet model is a vector containing the probability that the image belongs to each of the `n` classes, in your case to any of the 21 classes. If you want to use the ResNet model for semantic segmentation you should use a different model structure since the model in the linked video is used for a different type of task (classification). When performing segmentation the model output should be of size `(H, W, N_CLASSES)` instead of `(1, N_CLASSES)` which is the case for the model from the video.

Comment: Is there any documentation or any link where i can learn about the model structure for semantic segmentation using resnet? I cant seem to find any thing online

Comment: [This github repository](https://github.com/CSAILVision/semantic-segmentation-pytorch/blob/8f27c9b97d2ca7c6e05333d5766d144bf7d8c31b/mit_semseg/models/models.py#L170) contains an example where the ResNet architecture is used for a segmentation task, where all layers excep the average pooling and fully connected layer are used from the original ResNet architecture.